# How to develop Firefox Addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Please provide me some good references or web pages which you recommend for development of Firefox Addons.

Comment: Starting from Firefox 57, only extensions developed using WebExtensions APIs will be supported on Desktop Firefox and Firefox for Android. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

Answer (score 9):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School : Very detailed. Is tried to be always up do date.
- http://lifehacker.com/264490/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension
- http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/firefox-extension-resource-072307/ : Basically a link list.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Netbeans Plugin [Foxbeans](http://www.teesoft.info/content/blogcategory/15/51/lang,en/) which streamlines the whole development process.

Answer (score 0):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) has some functionality that is useful. It has auto completion for XUL tags and also can generate a skeleton structure for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Add-on SDK or Add-on BUilder (see: http://mzl.la/addonsdk) that simplify a lot the process of creating addon, especially for beginner, and for simple addon doesn't require specific platform knowledge (e.g. XUL)

Answer (score 0):

Also, to set up the best possible development environment, check the [instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment)
and/or use a [quick help](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/developer-profile/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start with the development is to go through the examples so that you can understand. Follow this link for some good examples
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples